# Assume $a x^{4}+b x^{4}+1$ is divisible by $x^{2}-x-1$. Find the value of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume $a x^{4}+b x^{4}+1$ is divisible by $x^{2}-x-1$. Find the value of $a$ and $b$.
I assumed $x^{2}-x-1$ to be equal to zero and then by some algebraic manipulation, I got $x^{5}=5 x+3$ and $x^{4}=3 x+2$. I replaced the their values in the polynomial and got $a[5 x+3]+b[3 x+2]+1$ and I don't know what to do next. Am I even on the right direction?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $bx^2$ rather than $bx^4$?

Comment: @Mark Bennet No, the orginal question says at it is

Comment: @Alan ah, let me post it, sorry for not posting it at one go

Comment: If it's $b x^4$ instead of $b x^2$, then the values of $a$ and $b$ are not uniquely determined. But if it's $b x^2$ the exercise makes sense.

Comment: I'd bet money there's a typo in the problem, if that's how you received it.  The zeroes of $ \ x^2 - x - 1 \ $ are asymmetrical about the $ \ y-$axis, while $ \ (a+b)x^4 + 1 \ \ , $ with $ \ a + b < 0 \ $ necessarily has _symmetric_ $ \ x-$intercepts.  On the other hand, there are solutions if the middle term is $ \ bx^3 , bx^2 \ , \  $ or $ \ bx \ \ , $ since the zeroes of $ \ x^2 - x - 1 \ $ are $ \ \phi \ $ and $ \ -\frac{1}{\phi} \ $ and there are simple relations between those numbers and their integer powers.  (I found solutions for $ \ bx^2 \ $ in a minute playing with _Desmos_.)

Comment: Coming back to this post, it seems that the "typo" may be in the exponent of the _first_ term, based on a result in the OP.  I will submit an answer on what may have been the intended question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quartic has four zeros (at the vertices of a square centred at $0$ in the complex plane) each of which has modulus $1/\sqrt[4]{|a+b|}$. The quadratic has zeros of different modulus. Therefore the quadratic cannot divide the quartic.

The problem is solvable if the implausible $bx^4$ term is replaced by $bx^2$. Then the coefficients of the odd-power terms in the quartic are zero only if the coefficient of the $x$ term in the other factor is $1$ while the other terms are $x^2$ and $-1$. Thus the other factor is $x^2+x-1$, and so $a=1$ and $b=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may have been intended that the polynomial is the *quintic* $ \ a \mathbf{x^5} + b x^4 + 1 \ \ , $ based on your remark that you computed "substitutions" for $ \ x^5 \ $ and $ \ x^4 \ \ . $  The divisor polynomial $ \ x^2 - x - 1 \ $ would be familiar to someone who has dealt with the "Golden  Ratio", as it has the real zeroes $ \ \phi \ $ and $ \ -\frac{1}{\phi} \ \ . $  The relations you worked out arise from the "basic" equation $ \ \phi \ = \ 1 + \frac{1}{\phi} \ \ . $  Repeated multiplications by $ \ \phi \ $ and simplifications of the resulting expressions lead to $ \ \phi^4 \ \ = \ \ 3·\phi \ +  \ 2 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \phi^5 \ \ = \ \ 5·\phi \ + \ 3 \ \ , $
as you found, and also $ \ \frac{1}{\phi^4} \ \ = \ \ 5 \ - \ 3·\phi  \ \ \ , \ \ \ -\frac{1}{\phi^5} \ \ = \ \ 8 \ - \ 5·\phi  \ \ . $  (It is perhaps unsurprising that the coefficients of this linear expressions are Fibonacci numbers.)

You were on the right track for solving the problem:  the "Factor Theorem" tells us that $ \ a  x^5  + b x^4 + 1 \   $ is divisible by $ \ x^2 - x - 1 \ $ if the zeroes of the latter polynomial are among the zeroes of the former one.  Upon inserting the above results into the polynomial equation $ \ a  x^5  + b x^4 + 1 \ = \ 0 \ \ ,  $ we obtain
$$ a · (5·\phi \ + \ 3) \  + \ b·(3·\phi \ +  \ 2) \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ (5a \ + \ 3b)·\phi \ + \ (3a \ + \ 2b \ + \ 1) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
We will want the factor multiplying $ \ \phi \ $ and the "constant term" both to equal zero, which leads us to the system of equations $ \ 5a + 3b \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ 3a + 2b \ = \ -1 \ \ , $ for which the solution is $ \ a \ = \ 3 \ \ , \ \  b \ = \ -5 \ \ . $  Performing the analogous calculation for $ \ x \ = \ -\frac{1}{\phi} \ \ , $
$$ a · (8 \ - \ 5·\phi) \  + \ b·(5 \ - \ 3·\phi) \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ -(5a \ + \ 3b)·\phi \ + \ (8a \ + \ 5b \ + \ 1) \ \ = \ \ 0     $$
returns the identical solutions for $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ \ . $  So there is a *unique* quintic polynomial $ \ 3x^5 - 5x^4 + 1 $ $ = \ (3x^3 - 2x^2 + x - 1)·(x^2 - x - 1) \ \ $ divisible by the specified polynomial.

[It should be said that there are likewise unique solutions for $ \ ax^4 + bx^3 + 1 \ \rightarrow \ -2x^4 + 3x^3 + 1 \  $ and $ \ ax^4 + bx^2 + 1 \ \rightarrow \ x^4 - 3x^3 + 1 \ \ $ (the polynomial **John Bentin** solves), since the problems ultimately present consistent systems of linear equations.
And we might well have expected that the coefficients of these polynomials are Fibonacci numbers as well.]

If we didn't recognize the influence of the Golden Ratio in this problem, we could still solve it by straight-ahead polynomial division:  dividing $ \ ax^5 + bx^4 + 1 \ $ by $ \ x^2 - x - 1 \ $ produces the quotient $ \ ax^3 + (a+b)x^2 + (2a+b)x + (3a+2b) \ $ with the remainder $ \ (5a + 3b)x + (3a + 2b + 1) \ \   $ (Fibonacci numbers again abound).  The requirement for the remainder to be zero gives us the system of equations we have already seen.